# Upload and Download File to server using Jquery C#

Tags: c#, jquery

How to upload and download file to server using jquery with HTML input tags in c# not with the code behind.

Comment: Look at the documentation and search for examples

Comment: Refer these Upload:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously Download:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax